# How to add elements around an already center-justified element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a form with some text elements aligned vertically like so:

[image: Items aligned vertically]

They are centered horizontally and vertically on the page using flexbox:

```
.my-class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

What I'm trying to do now is maintain this alignment (i.e. keep everything that's on the page already exactly where it is) while adding some elements on either side of the first text box. I tried wrapping everything in a `div` but since the elements on either side of the text box are not the same width, the text box loses its alignment:

[image: Items out of alignment]

As you can see, the long text boxes are now out of alignment. How can I add elements before and after the first text box without moving where it is?

Comment: When you add elements to the first box, you could add the exact same elements to the second box, and hide them with `visibility: hidden`... Or you could use CSS Grid Layout, which establishes columns and enables elements to move around without affecting surrounding elements.

Comment: Is there something I can do to make my answer acceptable?

Comment: @LGSon Sorry I haven't gotten around to looking at this yet. I'm hopefully planning on checking it out tomorrow if things don't light on fire :)

Comment: No problem :) ... just wanted to follow up on my answers

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is the *url/pass/button* that are the one's to be centered, and the *https/path* stick on each side, I would do it like this, where I use a flex *row* container and pseudo elements to break each group of item into lines of their own.

With this markup one also have full control to move around the items based on screen width's etc.

The 2 main things making this work is the pseudo elements, that, with their full width, force them into rows of their own, and at the same time push content down, together with the `order` property, enable to position them before the *pass* and *auth* respectively.

Stack snippet

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;     /*  horiz. center items  */
  align-content: center;       /*  vert. center wrapped items  */
  /*align-items: center;*/     /*  vert. center unwrapped items  */
}
.flex div:nth-child(1),
.flex div:nth-child(3) {       /*  https/path item  */
  flex: 1;                     /*  share space left equal  */
}
.flex div:nth-child(2),
.flex div:nth-child(4) {       /*  url/pass item  */
  flex-basis: 300px;           /*  need equal width  */
}
.flex::before {                /*  1st line breaker  */
  content: ''; width: 100%;
  order: 1;
}
.flex div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}
.flex::after {                 /*  2nd line breaker  */
  content: ''; width: 100%;
  order: 3;
}
.flex div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}

/*  styling  */
.flex {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.flex span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.flex div:nth-child(2) span,
.flex div:nth-child(4) span {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.flex div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div><span>http(s)</span></div>
  <div><span>url</span></div>
  <div><span>path</span></div>
  <div><span>***</span></div>
  <div><span>authenticate</span></div>
</div>
```

---

If the width of the *url/pass* should scale with parent's width, use percent combined with CSS Calc.

Stack snippet

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.flex div:nth-child(1),
.flex div:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
.flex div:nth-child(2),
.flex div:nth-child(4) {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}
.flex::before {
  content: ''; width: 100%;
  order: 1;
}
.flex div:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}
.flex::after {
  content: ''; width: 100%;
  order: 3;
}
.flex div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}

/*  styling  */
.flex {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.flex span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.flex div:nth-child(2) span,
.flex div:nth-child(4) span {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.flex div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div><span>http(s)</span></div>
  <div><span>url</span></div>
  <div><span>path</span></div>
  <div><span>***</span></div>
  <div><span>authenticate</span></div>
</div>
```

---

Another option would be to keep the initial flex *column* direction, and with an extra wrapper use absolute positioning for the *http(s)/path* items.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex > div:nth-child(-n+2) {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}
.flex div div:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}
.flex div div:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

/*  styling  */
.flex {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.flex span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.flex div div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
.flex div div:nth-child(1),
.flex div div:nth-child(3) {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <div><span>http(s)</span></div>
    <div><span>url</span></div>
    <div><span>path</span></div>
  </div>
  <div><span>***</span></div>  
  <div><span>authenticate</span></div>
</div>
```

---

Updated (based on another question with a similar need)

One can also keep the simpler markup, with no extra wrapper, and use `inline-flex` combine with making the `flex` parent also a flex container.

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex div:nth-child(2),
.flex div:nth-child(4) {
  width: 300px;
}
.flex div:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}
.flex div:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

/*  styling  */
.flex {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.flex span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: left;
}
.flex div div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}
.flex div div:nth-child(1),
.flex div div:nth-child(3) {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div><span>http(s)</span></div>
  <div><span>url</span></div>
  <div><span>path</span></div>
  <div><span>***</span></div>  
  <div><span>authenticate</span></div>
</div>
```